# How to run or launch a ros node without keeping the souce code

Tags: ros

**What I wanted**

I want to reduce my docker image size through removing a cloned source code from my workspace in 'src' directory according to [this](https://answers.ros.org/question/269046/is-it-possible-to-run-nodes-without-source/) suggestion. For that matter, I have just deployed my source code using the following commands:

```
    # install package
   sudo catkin config --install
   catkin_make
   catkin_make install
```

**The problem**

As a result, *install*  directory generate with many other library folders. I then navigated in to */share/* folder and tried to *roslaunch*  one of my launch file. This is the error that I got:

```
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [oxford_gps_eth/gps_node]: oxford_gps_eth
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/melodic/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/melodic/share
```

No processes to monitor
shutting down processing monitor...

**Expectation**

I was able to launch my node, even being in */install/share/* directory without removing the cloned source code in *'src'* directory.
I wanted to launch my nodes after building and remove my source code so that I can utilize my image.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what `share` dir you're navigating to? Are you talking about `/opt/ros/melodic/share`? Have you successfully installed the packages into `/opt/`?

Comment: I choose the default install directory. After running those "catkin make" commands,  three folder have been generated in the 'catking_ws' workspace it self. Namely, build, devel and install. So, I am talking about this install directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `source install/setup.bash`. This script will setup your environmental variables such as `PYHONPATH` and is what `roslaunch` uses to find packages.